# MVC Issue with Model appearing in Query String

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have built an MVC 5 Application that dynamically loads child applications from DLLs.  Everything works as expected but somewhere along the way, I noticed that my Models started to appear to be represented in the Query Strings despite using Post.

They are appearing like this:

> http://localhost:64921/Access/LookupUser?PageModel=AccessChecker.App.Models.UserLookup

While I would expect them to appear like this:

> http://localhost:64921/Access/LookupUser

Unfortunately this had to be put to the side for another project for some time and I am just getting back to it.  I know before I put it down, I attempted to rebuild a good portion of the application trying to tack the issue down and did not come across the cause of it.

Because my routes are dynamically generated, I cannot show a snippet of code, but here are the Route URL values (in order at runtime):

> "__browserLink/requestData/{requestId}"
>
> ""
>
> "api/{controller}/{id}"
>
> "{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}"
>
> "{controller}/{action}/{id}"
>
> "CAS/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
>
> "App1/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
>
> "App2/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
>
> "App3/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
>
> "Access/{controller}/{action}/{id}"

My Controller Action looks like this:

```
    public ActionResult LookupUser(UserLookup LookupModel, FormCollection FormData)
    {
        UserLookup UL = null;
        ...
        return View(UL);
    }
```

The form in the View looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LookupUser", Application.ApplicationPrefix, new { PageModel = Model }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "LookupArea", @class = (Model.Memberships.Count > 0 ? "LoadedWithContent" : ""), role = "form" }))
{
    ...
            <input type="submit" id="Submit_btn" value="Lookup" />
    ...
}
```

On top of numerous other attempts, I have tried taking out the default routes, moved "{controller}/{action}/{id}" to the end, taking out extraneous routes, removed ", FormCollection FormData" and plenty of things I have long since forgotten.  The URL that comes into Application_BeginRequest in Global.asax.cs has the model on it.

I have also rewritten or extended significant portions of the MVC Framework to enable the dynamic content from DLLs, security checking or error redirection, so it could have to do with some portion of that or it could be something simple like a form parameter or the route order (even though I attempted to check that).

Any guidance on where to narrow down the scope of where to look or insight as to what can cause this would be appreciated.

Comment: If these are Get actions, this is the default behavior because get doesn't support sending a body with parameters like a Post or Put action.

Comment: The intent is for it to be a Post when receiving data (the FormCollection is there for alternative calling methods).  If I set an HttpPost attribute, I am would need to have two different actions (one for the blank form with as a Get and one for the Post).

Comment: Just to be certain, I split out the code into two actions and had the same issue on the post.

Comment: Your adding the query string parameter because of your `new { PageModel = Model }` in the `BeginForm()` method. Remove it.

Comment: Stephen, thanks that worked.  I believe that I had to add it because of modifications I had previously made but changed it so that I was not reinventing as much of the wheel.  After removing it as you suggested, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stephen's recommendation above corrected my issue (which was mostly just seeing the trees through the forest).